# Direction of friction force on rotating and slipping sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

An homogeneous sphere of mass $m$ and radius $r$ with only initial rotation $|\dot\phi(t=0)|= \omega_0$ is placed over an horizontal surface , with initial velocity of translation of the center of mass $\dot R(t=0)= 0 $. Until the sphere starts rolling without slipping,besides its movement of rotations, it must necessarily slips.The movement of the center of mass of the sphere occurs along the positive x axis(to the right).

I was asked to draw the force diagram of the situation above. I know I have weight, normal and friction force.
However I am not sure about the direction of the friction force.
Since the center of mass has no initial velocity of translation and the friction force is the only one that produces torque then it should point to the right in order to accelerate the center of mass. But in my head friction should point to the left to reduce the translation velocity so the ball could start rolling without slipping(pure rolling).

Any help will be appreciated ,thank you

Comment: "But in my head friction should point to the left to reduce the translation velocity so the ball could start rolling without slipping(pure rolling)." Does the translation velocity have to slow down, or can something else slow down...

Comment: The rotation velocity $\omega(t)$ can be slowed down. So the friction points to the right to accelerate the center of mass but it reduces the rotation velocity?

Comment: Correct! Now to really understand it, think about what's going to happen for $t > 0$ and in the limit for a long time later, $t >> 0$ (you'll reach rolling without slipping, of course).